# What is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Invalid value "3" for parameter "columnIndex" [90008-200]?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-security

I'm trying to use JDBC authentication for my spring security when I hit the error message below. I'm trying to register all the email and password in the User class to be valid logins. I'm not sure if there is a problem with my sql statement or my User class. Any help if appreciated!

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: 
Invalid value "3" for parameter "columnIndex" [90008-200]
```

Spring security

```
    @Autowired      
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
                throws Exception {          
           auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                // To find logins in the h2 database
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select email, password " +
                                "from User " +
                                "where email = ?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select email, role " +
                                "from User " +
                                "where email =?");
 
     }
```

User class

```
     @Entity
     public class User {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        @Size(min = 6, message ="Enter at least 6 characters")
        @ValidPassword
        private String password;
        private String matchingPassword;
        private String passportNumber;
        private String address;
        private String phoneNumber;
        @ValidEmail
        private String email;
        
        // Mark as primary key
        @Id
        // Will be auto generated
        @GeneratedValue
        private long id;
        private String role;
    
        
    
        public User(@NotNull String firstName, @NotNull String lastName,
                @Size(min = 6, message = "Enter at least 6 characters") @NotNull String password,
                @NotNull String passportNumber, @NotNull String address, @NotNull String phoneNumber, String email,
                String role) {
            super();
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.password = password;
            this.passportNumber = passportNumber;
            this.address = address;
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            this.email = email;
            this.role = role;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", password=" + password
                    + ", matchingPassword=" + matchingPassword + ", passportNumber=" + passportNumber + ", address="
                    + address + ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber + ", email=" + email + ", id=" + id + ", role=" + role + "]";
        }
    
        public String getRole() {
            return role;
        }
    
        public void setRole(String role) {
            this.role = role;
        }
    
        
    
    
    
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
    
    
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    
    
        public String getMatchingPassword() {
            return matchingPassword;
        }
    
    
        public void setMatchingPassword(String matchingPassword) {
            this.matchingPassword = matchingPassword;
        }
    
    
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }
    
    
        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
    
    
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
    
    
        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    
    
        public String getPassportNumber() {
            return passportNumber;
        }
    
    
        public void setPassportNumber(String passportNumber) {
            this.passportNumber = passportNumber;
        }
    
    
        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }
    
    
        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }
    
    
        public String getPhoneNumber() {
            return phoneNumber;
        }
    
    
        public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }
    
    
    
        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
    
        protected User() {
            
        }
    
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
    }
```

EDIT: Answer to this question is marked below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Spring security expects 3 columns for the `usersByUserName` query. Here is the default query used if you don't specify one.

```
    public static final String DEF_USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY 
        = "select username, password, enabled from users where username = ?";
```

- So if you don't have such column for enabling and disabling user, use the following query

```
    select email, password, 'true' as enabled from User where email = ?
```

**Reference**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html

Comment: what if I don't have enabled column?